# Fish shell - advanced control flow

Tags: shell, fish, control-flow

Normally, fish shell processes commands like this:

```
1 && 3 (2)
```

This is perfectly useful and it mirrors the order of execution that I would want most of the time.

I was wondering if a different syntax exists to get a slightly different order of execution?

Sometimes I want this:

```
2 && 3 (1)
```

is that possible without using multiple lines ?

This is a trivial example:

```
cd ~ && cat (pwd | psub)
```

In this example I want to run `pwd` first then run `cd` and then run `cat`

edit: oh! This seems to work:

cat (pwd | psub && cd ~)

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those cases where I'm going to recommend just using multiple lines [0].

It's cleaner and clearer:

```
set -l dir (pwd)
cd ~ && cat (printf '%s\n' $dir | psub)
```

This is completely ordinary and straightforward, and that's a *good* thing. It's also easily extensible - want to run the `cd` only if the `pwd` succeded?

```
set -l dir (pwd)
and cd ~ && cat (printf '%s\n' $dir | psub)
```

as `set` passes on the previous $status, so here it passes on the status of `pwd`.

The underlying philosophy here is that fish script isn't built for code golf. It doesn't have many shortcuts, even ones that posix shell script or especially shells like bash and zsh have. The fish way is to simply write the code.

---

Your answer of

```
cat (pwd | psub && cd ~)
```

doesn't work because that way the `cat` is no longer only executed if the `cd` succeeds - command substitutions can fail. Instead the `cd` is now only done if the `psub` succeeded - notably this also happens if `pwd` fails.

(of course that `cat (pwd | psub)` is fairly meaningless and could just be `pwd`, I'm assuming you have some actual code you want to run like this)

---

[0]: Technically this doesn't *have* to be multiple lines, you can write it as `set -l dir (pwd); cd ~ && cat (printf '%s\n' $dir | psub)`. I would, however, also recommend using multiple lines